# this.context does not contain router when using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I am using a combination of React, Redux, react-router, react-router-redux. I have a component that needs to push a URL to the browser's history. In the latest version of react-router (2.0.0-rc5), I have a component with the following properties:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.context) // empty object, where is router?
  }
}
```

Comment: did you bind your testFunction to `this` somewhere?

Comment: The `this` references the TestComponent. I added the same `console.log` statement inside of `render`, and it's still empty.

Comment: It does not actually. `this` is not autobound to functions not extended by `Component`. Try adding `this.testFunction = this.testFunction.bind(this)` in your class constructor.

Comment: Also, this isn't your actual code is it? Functions need `()` after them `testFunction()`. and class properties are set with `=`. Most cases you would see `static contextTypes = { router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired }`

Comment: Hey, I edited the post so it reflects the code more. It still doesn't work even when I define the class property like that.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I forgot to change the `:` to `=` when defining the class property like you mentioned. Now it's working! Thanks! If you want to post your fix as an answer, I can accept it. It's confusing because in the react-router docs, they define class properties differently: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#changes-to-thiscontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to have been a syntax error in class property initialization.

You have two options:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }; // required semi-colon!
  ...
}
```

But class properties are still a beta feature so it's not uncommon to see:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  ...
}

TestComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
} // semi-colon not required
```

Also make sure to use parens in your class functions!

```
testFunction() {
  // do stuff
}
```